# Best way to store objects TFile via rootpy

Tags: python, root-framework, rootpy

I am trying to store a python class (or just the members) in a ROOT file (CERN, `TFile`) via rootpy.

I can easily do this using a `Tree` and a `TreeModel` but that only works for basic types and does not result in the structure I am looking for.
I had also a quick look at `rootpy.io.pickler` but that does not allow the inspection with a `TBrowser` (it crashes).

I was wondering if there is a better way. What I would like to have

My file:

- directory of my choosing

  - directory with the name of my object
  - object basic types (int, float, string)
  - histograms (that one is easy)
  - other complex objects

As you see this cannot be realised with a `Tree` and I do not know how to add the basic types to a `Directory`. Any ideas?

I would like to avoid, if possible, the logical work-around of storing the object parameters in a tree and the histograms directly in the same `Directory`.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have is to create the TDirectory you want in your TFile and add the contents to this directory. Histograms are easy. The basic types could be stored in a tree. For other complex objects you could have a look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). The serialized object (i.e. `pickle_string = pickle.dumps(Foo)`) can then be stored in a tree as a string without breaking inspection via TBrowser. This works without rootpy, just using PyROOT. I hope this might help.